# Using MySQL workbench, how to prevent new foreing key columns when modeling

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench

I'm reverse-engineering a database and specifying relationships.  MySQL workbench wants add foreign-key columns as I do this.

While I see the benefit of this, I would like to turn off this default behavior since the columns already exist (just using a different name than what Workbench is expecting).

I'm using Mysql 5.5.49 and Workbench 6.3.6 on Ubuntu if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a relationship you can use one of the tools reachable with the buttons in the vertical toolbar (or the hotkeys 1-6). The last one ([image]) is what you are looking for. It let's you pick the columns to be used for a relationship instead of creating new columns for it.